# OBIEE Creating a Custom JOIN to pull in two of the same columns but with different data

Tags: obiee

I am new to OBIEE and need assistance with an issue. I only have access to the front end not the RPD.
I have a subject area that has product information on books, such as ID, Product Description, Edition etc... Product Description and Edition I believe are joined to ID. 
I have another field that will show the future ID's of the Products called "To Item". To Item consists of the same structure and data as ID.
I would like to be able to pull in the Description and Edition base don these ID's in To Item. However I would need to create a new JOIN to do so, but I am unable to do so. Can anyone possibly help me with steps on how I could this and the type of syntax

Answer (score 0):

Without access to the RPD you shouldn't even start thinking about doing something like this because it's what the RPD is there for and the front-end is not at all made to change anything in terms of data structure.

Comment: Hi Chris, sorry I can access the RPD to see the relationships, however I do not have control to change anything I meant to say. Thanks for the advice though. An ETL may be the only option then

Comment: Yes ETL would work but you should think about what makes sense in terms of effort and performance

Comment: Could you give me any indication as to any alternatives? is it possible to create joins in the Sql section of the advanced tab or in the column formula?

Comment: No. Do things correctly and properly. Either in the RPD or while ETL'ing the data. You also wouldn't try to add a sail to your car rather than learning how to drive.